# How can you see field comments from mysql client?

Tags: mysql, database-design, documentation, comments

I would like to see individual fields comments. Typically something I would expect from "describe" parameters.

```
mysql> describe metrics;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ty    | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| t     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| s     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 60000   |                |
| e     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| c     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
show full columns from <table_name>
```

This is the output:

```
| Field | Type | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges | Comment
```

I hope this is useful for you

Answer (score 12):

This query will give you much more information than the `describe` statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'metrics'
AND table_schema = '...' -- Optionally, filter the schema as well, to avoid conflicts
```

Comment: you need search DB **table_schema**, a example: `WHERE table_name = 'my_table' and table_schema = 'my_db'`

Comment: @KingRider: You're right, thanks. That would be more complete. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 10):

always You could use:

```
show create table <tablename>
```

Comment: Doesn't give you comments in a parsable format