# How can I get all attributes of a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

[image]
As you can see above, columns have 13 attributes, they respectively are

- Field
- Type
- Length
- Unsigned
- Zerofill
- Binary
- Allow Null
- Key
- Default
- Extra
- Encoding
- Collation
- Comment

I can see them because I'm using a visual mysql client software, but if I'm using a Terminal, a commandline client, I can only see the following attributes

```sql
mysql> desc user;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| nickname | varchar(50)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| age      | tinyint      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are no zerofill, binary, encoding, collation and comment in the result of `desc <tbl_name>`, any other commands can see these attributes? especially comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the columns metadata table to get this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE (table_schema='schema_name' and table_name = 'table_name')
order by ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12687400/7807426), that is

```sql
show full columns from <tbl_name>;
```

Example

```sql
mysql> show full columns from user;
+----------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+----------+
| Field    | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment  |
+----------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+----------+
| id       | int unsigned | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references | id       |
| name     | varchar(20)  | utf8mb4_general_ci | NO   | MUL |         |                | select,insert,update,references | name     |
| nickname | varchar(50)  | utf8mb4_general_ci | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references | nickname |
| age      | tinyint      | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references | age      |
+----------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not all attributes, but as least it show up the comments.